# Mantener seleccionado boton despues de abrir dialogo el cual fue hecho con un Activity

Tags: android

Tengo dos botones asi :

```
btnSurPlace.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.setPressed(true);

            // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;

            // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;

            onPlace = true;
            btnEmporter.setPressed(false);
            return true;
        }
    });

    btnEmporter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;

            // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;

            onPlace = false;
            v.setPressed(true);
            btnSurPlace.setPressed(false);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

El problema es que en la activity abro un dialogo hecho con un Activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".MenuDialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth" />
```

Al abrir tal Dialogo , el boton seleccionado se deselecciona.

¿Como puedo hacer que el boton que la persona seleccionó,siga seleccionado incluso despues de abrir y cerrar el Dialogo.

Answer (score 0):

Me resulta un poco raro esto de mantener "presionado" el botón pero puedes realizarlo mediante la propiedad:

```
setPressed(true);
```

ejemplo:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         btn.setPressed(true);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ya esta presionado, si funciona mi codigo , lo pongo en estado presionado true y se pinta de un color, pero al abrir el dialog, el setPressed pasa a false .